# Django admin panel multi-choose

Tags: django, django-admin

Я пытаюсь реализовать в админ-панели Django multi-choose, то есть чтобы для модели с несколькими полями был выбор, причем для кажой свой, а так же я хочу, чтобы при выборе для одного из полей значения другие значения фильтровались.

Например:
есть модель **транспортное средство**, которая может принимать значения *грузовик* и *автомобиль*
и есть модель **топливо** - может принимать значения *92*, *95*, *86*
Я хочу в админке реализовать два выпадающих меню для **транспортного средства** и для **топлива**, при этом чтобы если был выбран *грузовк*, то в выпадающем меню топлива был выбран только *86* бензин

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вам необходимо использовать [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

В примере из документации выбор в поле car ограничивается только теми записями, владельцем (поле owner) в которых является текущий пользователь

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```